# How can I do "Map" on a binary function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, map

If there is a one-variable function, we can `f/@{a,b,c}` to get `{f[a],f[b],f[c]}`

What to do with it if it comes to a binary function `f[#1,#2]&`, and a list `{a,b,c}`

and we want to "Map" it into a list funtion `{f[#1,a],f[#1,b],f[#1,c]}&`

I have found a strange way:

```
MapThread[f,{Table[#,3],{a,b,c}]&
```

though mathematica can't expand it, but it can actually work?! [doge]

if we add `[x]` behind it, we get the answer

```
MapThread[f,{Table[#,3],{a,b,c}]&[x]
>>> {f[x, a], f[x, b], f[x, c]}
```

Comment: `Function@Evaluate@Map[Function[x, f[#, x]]]@{a, b, c}`?

Comment: .. or `Evaluate[f @@@ Thread[{#, {a, b, c}}]] &`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Function[{x},f[y,x]] /@ {a,b,c} //
Function[y,#]&
```

> Function[y, {f[y, a], f[y, b], f[y, c]}]

Also, you may want to check this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying